# How can I speed up this MySQL Date Equal Query?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, date

```
SELECT SPX.date, SPX.value, GS.value, IBM.value
  FROM SPX, GS, IBM
  WHERE SPX.date=GS.date AND GS.date=IBM.date AND
  SPX.date >= '2007-04-22' AND SPX.date <= '2012-04-22'
  ORDER BY Date ASC
```

I'm a beginner at MySQL and am trying to do some things with financial data. The above query shows my attempt to get a pool of data for stocks SPX, GS, and IBM. This query is not that fast, however. Is there a way to speed it up?

This is also daily data, so in this example there are about 1500 data points for each stock

Comment: please post your table schema (create script)

Comment: Have you added an index to the date columns of each table?

Comment: Can you paste the output of EXPLAIN on your query, too?

Comment: I figured it out. It used to take 2 seconds to process, but once I added an index to the date columns, it became much faster (why??).